# mongoimport removes first record

Tags: json, mongodb, csv

On CSV import - mongo is removing the first record. Any ideas why?

```
mongoimport --file abilities.csv --type csv --db talent --headerline --collection abilities
```

Comment: Is your first line in the csv the field names?

Comment: Yes, the first line contains the field names. Then in the collection - everything looks great - it's just the first record from the CSV is gone.

Comment: Type 'use talent' then 'db.abilities.count()' into the mongo repl after importing and see what you get.  Compare to how many records you think you should have.  I just want to confirm it's only the first record missing.  Also, not sure why json is tagged in the question, please confirm you are importing a csv and not a json file.

Comment: 99217 & 99217! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked and it just didn't import in order. For some reason, the document was on a different list page. All worked out! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Great.  Since everything in mongo is stored as an object you can never predict the order in which data will be stored.

Comment: That's good to know; I'm still a working it as a novice user - those nuances of SQL that I have to leave behind.